# The Thomson scattering optical depth for a photon ar radius r

Tags: optics, photons, astrophysics

I am looking to understand some more about the physics of gamma ray bursts. In particular I am looking at the origin of the "prompt emission". Some of the energy associated with this prompt emission is thought to come from the photosphere of the expanding fireball at the centre of the GRB, which expands at relativistic speeds.

The Thomson scattering optical depth for a photon at radius $r$ is give n by

$$\tau = \int \frac{dr}{c} (c-v) \sigma_T n_e  $$

where $c$ is the speed of light, $n_e$ the electron number density and $\sigma_T$ the scattering cross section and $v$ the velocity of the expanding fireball.

Can anyone give me a physical explanation behind this equation? Also, at the photospheric radius, the optical depth becomes 1. Why should this be so? Thanks

Comment: Some context is required. Also, what is $v$?

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: The answer to your last question is that the photospheric radius is defined as last scattering surface of photons originally trapped in the ejecta, i.e. where the ejecta becomes opticall thin, i.e. where $\tau\sim 1$. Wrt. to your first question, where did you see this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of this equation is reasonably well explained in [Abramowicz (1991)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1991ApJ...369..175A).

If you take a relativistically expanding enevelope and only consider Thomson scattering, then as the electron scattering cross-section in the co-moving frame $\sigma_T$ is independent of frequency, then the mean free path of a photon in the co-moving frame is independent of the envelope velocity as seen in the "stationary" (observers) frame.

Abramowicz et al. shows that in the case of photons moving "downstream", i.e. with the flow 
$$ d\tau = \gamma (1 - \beta) d\tau_0,$$
where $\beta = v/c$, $\gamma = (1-\beta^2)^{-1/2}$ is the Lorentz factor, $\tau_0$ is the optical depth in the co-moving frame and $\tau$ is the optical depth in the observer's frame.

Now $\tau_0(r) = \int_{r}^{\infty} n_{e,0} \sigma_T\ dr$, so
$$  \tau(r) = \int^{\infty}_{r} \gamma (1 - \beta)  n_{e,0} \sigma_T\ dr,$$
where $n_{e,0}$ is the electron density in the co-moving frame.

But if $ v\ll c$ then $\gamma (1 - \beta) \simeq (1- \beta)$ and $n_{e,0} \simeq n_e$ thus

$$  \tau(r) \simeq  \int_{r}^{\infty} (1 - \beta) n_e \sigma_T\ dr = \int_{r}^{\infty} \frac{(c-v)}{c}  n_e \sigma_T\ dr$$

The integral is carried out from some physical depth in the wind out to infinity. The Thomson scattering photosphere can be defined as where this optical depth is approximately unity. This is because this will be roughly where the radiation decouples from the flow and photons can escape.

Comment: Great answer! Just one thing: can you explain further on the significance of the optical depth being unity? I understand optical depth is the natural log of the incident over the transmitted. SO surely a optical depth of 1 just means that the amount of incident radiation is 'e' times bigger than that which is transmitted?

Comment: The mean free path of a photon corresponds to an optical depth of unity. That would mean the average photon makes it to infinity.It's a handwaving definition. Sometimes $\tau=2/3$ is used, because this is where the average number of scatterings drops below 1. Basically, you can "see into" an atmosphere/envelope to a depth corresponding to $\tau \sim 1$. Possibly you have not worked out that the integral is not from the centre to $r$. It is from $r$ to $\infty$? Limits added.